# How to add support for .tex files in quicksilver?

Tags: macos, latex, quicksilver

I would like to open a tex file with a selected application (fraise, texShop, or texmate) in the [quicksilver](http://www.blacktree.com/projects/quicksilver.html). I can not find any information about how to do that. Have anybody made Quicksilver opening tex files?

UPDATE: I could not see .tex file in Quicksilver, because it took some time till it was indexed by macos. So the answer is: Quicksilver has no problems with tex files.

Comment: By the way, if you want to update the Quicksilver catalog, press 'Cmd' + R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also invoke Quicksilver -> Select file.tex -> Tab and select 'open with' -> tab and select another than the default application.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to invoke Quicksilver -> type application of interest, tab -> type "file" to select the *Open File…* action, tab -> type the LaTeX document you want to open, enter. This works for me on Quicksilver ß58 (3841).